# DateTime Conversion in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

How can I convert `'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff'` to `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS.MS'` format so that I can store timestamp values in a PostgreSQL 8.0.2 `timestamp` column?

Comment: Ok, slowly: You have character fields containing the given format and want to convert them to a Timestamp?

Comment: More context please. Convert them within Postgres? In your programming language of choice (which?!) before inserting into Postgres?

Comment: Thanks, i'm uploading application generated csv files to Amazon S3 and using copy command, the data from the files are inserted into PostgreSql tables. I've made changes to my app. to generate YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fff format text, but the problem is i want to upload the existing files that are already generated with DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS.fff format and don't want to regenerate them.

Comment: If PostgreSQL **8.0.2** isn't a typo, you have more serious problems than formatting timestamps. [v8.0 has reached EOL in 2010](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Consider upgrading to a more current version.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you don't have to convert the format, just switch to european datestyle before issuing `COPY`.

The command is:

```
SET datestyle to 'DMY';
```